# Spring Boot + Spring Data JPA - задержанное соединение

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-jpa, spring-data-jpa

Спринг Бут при наличии конфигурации БД сразу поднимает соединение с БД и проверяет её. Если соединение с БД нету - сразу выкидывается ошибка и приложение прекращает работу.

Если подключение у БД медленное, как её конфигурировать чтоб само подключение произошло только во время операции с БД?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте добавить

```
spring.datasource.continue-on-error=true
```

> https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html
>
> spring.datasource.continue-on-error=false # Whether to stop if an
>   error occurs while initializing the database

Comment: Спасибо, да это решает проблему при инициализации, но это сработает при выполнении команд?